# Create BeakerX TableDisplay in Python Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm having troubles getting started with [`BeakerX`](http://beakerx.com/). I just want to display a table in a `Python` `Jupyter` notebook like how they show in their [Python API for Table Display Jupyter Notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/twosigma/beakerx/blob/master/doc/python/TableAPI.ipynb):

```python
import pandas as pd
from beakerx import *
from beakerx.object import beakerx
beakerx_table = TableDisplay(pd.read_csv('./dspace_BMTs.csv.bz2'))
beakerx_table
```

There are no errors, but there is also no apparent output.  Unfortunately a side-effect is that normal Jupyter Notebook output is also suppressed.  I.e., later in the notebook, `df.head()` shows nothing.  Without `BeakerX`, `Jupyter`/`Pandas` behaves normally.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but uninstalling and reinstalling the `beakerx` components fixed this issue.

```
$ beakerx uninstall
$ beakerx install
```

Comment: I installed `beakerx` on another laptop and it had the same issue and resolution.... install, uninstall, install.